# Is it possible to specify Service fabric reverse proxy for a request having its own query string

Tags: reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

We can have service fabric reverse proxy and specify "PartitionKey" as query string. So, using reverse proxy and "PartitionKey" query string, is it possible to specify a different query string in my API request?

My API will be like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{someId:Guid}/myapimethod")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyApiMethod(Guid someId, string queryForApiPurpose){ ………..}
```

The call to the above API without reverse proxy will be like

> http://clusteraddress/api/d281be34-c3f8-414a-9484-2e8f40607dab/myapimethod?queryForApiPurpose=avalue

What will be the call to above API when coming through reverse proxy when I also have a "PartitionKey"? I am guessing we wouldn’t be able to use query strings in requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can add query string parameters to a request through the Reverse Proxy, and they will be forwarded along to the target service.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Will you please be able to provide a sample for that.